# How to Loop Multiple TextBoxes to set Transparency

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set transparency levels to 60% on multiple textboxes using VBA. I am using the following code to loop TextBox 100 - 149, when executing I encounter a runtime error `The item with the specified name was not found` How can I resolve?

```
Sub set_Transparency()
Dim x As Integer
For x = 100 To 149
With Sheet5.Shapes("TextBox" & x)
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
        With .Font.Fill
.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
.Transparency = 0
    End With
        End With
End With
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you text boxes named "TextBox1" or "TextBox 1", with a space?

Comment: @BigBen "TextBox 1"

Comment: Then you're missing a space in `Shapes("TextBox"`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon still getting a runtime error even with the space added

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon figured it out, i don't have a textbox named "TextBox 110"

Comment: @AAA your solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub set_Transparency()
Dim x As Integer
For x = 100 To 149
With Sheet5.Shapes("TextBox " & x)
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
        With .Font.Fill
          .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
          .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With
End With
    Next x
End Sub
```